# intellij with sbt scala and android dev

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, proguard

probably a silly mistake, trying to use intellij idea with scaloid template.
App packages just fine in sbt console but can't make it work with IDEA though I set the right java 7 sdk. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error notes `Unsupported class version number [52.0]`, which means the class is expecting a Java 8 JDK.

Comment: yes indeed, I was actually trying to do the other way around.